# How to benchmark in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The database has a column `Booking Count` (can be more than 1) against every `passenger_id` (unique id).

"Booking Date" against each entry I am creating a dashboard which has to have:

1. % of booking shares
2. % increase or decrease compared to the last month

ex:

```
Passenger_id  Booking count Booking Date
axxxx           4              3/3/2015
acccc           1              3/5/2015
```

How do I do it on Tableau?
Please help me.

Comment: I'm dying to help you, but I really don't understand what you're asking at all. Could you clarify what you mean and provide some example output?

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Thanks for the reply! I will edit the question to add a screenshot of what I want to put on the dashboard.

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I wasnt able to post screenshots or attach files here ...so I have put it up on the Tableau forum... Please look into it.   http://community.tableau.com/message/422958#422958